# Variable Scope in methods

Tags: java, scope

The question is from the famous SCJP 6 book

> 13. Given:
>
>     ```
>     public class Dark {
>         int x = 3;
>
>         public static void main(String[] args) {
>             new Dark().go1();
>         }
>
>         void go1() {
>             int x;
>             go2(++x);
>         }
>
>         void go2(int y) {
>             int x = ++y;
>             System.out.println(x);
>         }
>     }
>     ```
>
>     What is the result?
>
>     A. 2
>       B. 3
>       C. 4
>       D. 5
>       E. Compilation fails
>       F. An exception is thrown at runtime

The answer according to the book is:

> ✓ E is correct. In go1() the local variable x is not initialized.

My questions is why go1() cannot use instance variable x initialized as 6 on line 4 here?

Comment: `go1()` has defined a local variable named `x` which hides the instance variable `x`. The local `x` hasn't been initialized, thus the compilation error.

Comment: @GriffeyDog  Actually in Java, **hiding** applies "only to members which would otherwise be inherited but are not because of a declaration in a subclass". This is an instance of [shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1).

Comment: @azurefrog I'm aware of that difference. I was trying to use terminology that might be more understandable to a beginner. Perhaps that wasn't the best choice in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the local variable x exists. If `int x;` were commented out, it will run fine and use the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Java all the local variables should be initialized if not it will give an error. But you shouldn't initialize parameters of a method.

if you don't have `int x` then this will be ok. because at that case compiler will use the local variable which is assigned for class level.